# How to obtain long edge between black and white thresholds?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, canny-operator, sobel

Using OpenCv I was converted green areas to white(255) and black(0): see CURRENT OUTPUT.

Using Canny, Laplacian and Sobel edge detection yielded many little edges, instead of a long consistent edge see CANNY EDGE Example.

How could I achieve one long edge as seen in the desired output?

Relevant Code:

```
image = cv.imread('grass pic.jpg')
lane_image = np.copy(image)
pic = cv.cvtColor(lane_image ,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

lower = np.array([24,0,0])
upper = np.array([177, 194, 20])

green_selection = cv.inRange(pic, lower, upper)
canny= cv.Canny(green_selection,50,150)

plt.imshow(canny, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

CURRENT OUTPUT:

[image: Current Output]

CANNY EDGE Example

[image: Canny Edge]

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 1):

Converting the image to HSV colour space might help you to detect your desired line.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.png")
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low = np.array([23, 98, 0])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, low, high)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

| Mask Image | Result Image |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |